# How many things get done, as more people are around to do them?

Tags: combinatorics

I have $N$ actions that people can do and $M$ people that can do them. Each person can do any number of actions $\in\{0,1,\ldots,M\}$ and each action can be done by any number of people$\in\{0,1,\ldots,N\}$.

But people won't do many actions, and actions won't have many people do them. Specifically: If we let $\mu(n)$ be the number of people who do exactly $n$ actions apiece, then assume $\mu$ decreases.

I want to increase the exposure of people to the total set of actions, while keeping that set constant: that is, I want to increase $M$. How can I express the number of distinct actions performed (this is a number $\le N$) as a function of $M$ and $\mu$?

(If you want to substitute other definition of $\mu$ which also expresses the idea that people won't do many actions and that actions won't have many people do them, feel free.)

Comment: Someone voted to close this as "unclear what you're asking" but didn't comment seeking clarification. I'd love to clarify anything unclear, but have no idea what is.

Comment: So you're looking for $\nu(M)$ in terms of what?

Comment: @TiwaAina, no, $\nu(M)$ is the number of distinct actions done per person by exactly $M$ people. Since there is no number of distinct actions done per person by exactly $M$ people (most likely), $M$ is not in the domain of $\nu$. I'm looking for the number of distinct actions done by the whole set of people in toto, not the number done per person. But actually your comment made me realize that $\nu$ is not necessarily well-defined, since there can be (e.g.) both 4 actions apiece done by exactly 2 people and 3 actions apiece done by exactly 2 (other) people. Let me rewrite….

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broadly defined problem. You can't really say anything useful without more restrictions. The number of distinct actions performed is obviously at at least equal to the largest value of $n$ such that $\mu(n)>0$, and that's basically all that can be said.

More specifically, take any decreasing sequence of integers $\mu(n)$ which is eventually $0$. Let $n$ be the largest value such that $\mu(n)>0$. Then we have $\sum^n_0\mu(k)$ people and at least $n$ possible actions. It might just be that $\mu(n)$ people are each performing actions $1$ through $n$, $\mu(n-1)$ of them are performing actions $1$ through $n-1$, etc. So $n$ distinct actions are being performed all in all.

Comment: Ye-es. Perhaps I shoulda formulated my question in terms of probability rather than combinatorics.